Generate csv template with dropdown list in react
I want my users to be able to download a default spreadsheet file with some fields having drop-down values. I know how to do this with Excel/Google Sheets but I'm unable to do this programmatically with React (using a package like Sheets).
Normally, I would manually create the xlsx. file, but the dropdown fields are fairly dynamic. So, I need to generate the spreadsheet template with an up-to-date version of the dropdown fields (after fetching the dropdown data from an external API).
I found someone on Stackoverflow trying to do something similar but no solutions
const handleDownloadCsvTemplate = () => {
  if (!selectedCategoryId) return;

  const selectedCategory = categories.find(
    (cat) => cat.id === selectedCategoryId,
  );
  if (!selectedCategory) return;

  const headers = selectedCategory.specification.map((spec) => spec.name);
  const csvContent = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + headers.join(',') + '\n';
  const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
  link.setAttribute('download', `${selectedCategory.name}_template.csv`);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};

